# TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED accessibility service

Tags: android, accessibility-api

In lollipop there is a new accessibility event called TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED but when I use it in my xml configuration file, I receive error from Android Studio. It it possible to add it only via code? Am I missing something?

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? What version of the Gradle for Android plugin are you using? What is the error?

Comment: @CommonsWare Android Studio 1.2.1.1, Gradle 1.2.3 and the error is "Cannot resolve flag"

Comment: @CommonsWare My fault, I meant TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED.

Comment: What is your `compileSdkVersion`? It need to be 21 or higher to resolve things added in API Level 21.

Comment: compileSdkVersion 22, the problem is the xml attribute because I can see the flag in the code

Comment: Hmmmm... feels like a bug then. I don't see anything filed on it. If you can upload the configuration file and a description of the symptoms to https://b.android.com, the tools team is pretty good about getting that sort of stuff fixed.

Comment: do you think is a bug of android studio? can you repost the link? It seems broken

Comment: "do you think is a bug of android studio?" -- that or the Gradle for Android plugin. I am not completely clear on where these sorts of Lint checks come from. And sorry, try http://b.android.com.

Comment: any other event can i use when window is opening? @CommonsWare.