# Cannot use TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED event in Accessibility Android

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

i searching about accessibility event called when android app window is changing. i found one question in stack over flow related to what i am searching.

Link is : [TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED accessibility service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573589/type-windows-changed-accessibility-service)

By studying this comments i am getting it can be done in only api level 21 or above. but i need to use it in lower version also like api level 14. how can i use TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED in api level 14 too. if TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED cannot be used in api level 14 then what event can i use when new activity or window opened. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i don't know about TYPE_WINDOW_CHANGED. As per your second question for opening a new activity or window, you can use the below event type.

**TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED**

the above event will be triggered when you open new activity or window,

Comment: TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED is getting called multiple times when we switch to a new application. Beware!